# Scraping HTML webpage using R

Tags: html, web-scraping, html-table, nodes, rvest

I am scraping JFK's website to get flight schedules. The link to the flight schedules is here;

http://www.flightview.com/airport/JFK-New_York-NY-(Kennedy)/departures

To begin with, I am inspecting the one of the fields of any given flight and noting down its xpath. Idea is to see the output and then develop the code from there. This is what I have so far:

```
library(rvest)

Departure_url <- read_html('http://www.flightview.com/airport/JFK-New_York-NY-(Kennedy)/departures')

Departures <- Departure_url %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="ffAlLbl"]') %>% html_text()
```

I am getting an empty character object as output for 'Departures' object in the code above.

I am not sure why this happens. I am looking for a node through which the entire schedule can be downloaded.

Any help is appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

To scrape that table is kind of tricky.

First of all, what you try to scrape is live content. So you need a headless browser such as RSelenium.

Second, the content is actually inside an iframe that is inside another iframe, so you need to use **switch to frame** twice.

Finally, the content is not a table, so you need to get all vectors and combine them into a table.

The following code should do the job:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(glue)
library(tidyverse)


#Rselenium
rmDr <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome")
myclient <- rmDr$client
myclient$navigate("http://www.flightview.com/airport/JFK-New_York-NY-(Kennedy)/departures")
#Switch two frame twice
webElems <- myclient$findElement(using = "css",value = "[name=webfidsBox]")
myclient$switchToFrame(webElems)
webElems <- myclient$findElement(using = "css",value = "#coif02")
myclient$switchToFrame(webElems)

#get page souce of the content
myPagesource <- read_html(myclient$getPageSource()[[1]])
selected_node <- myPagesource %>% html_node("#fvData")
#get content as vectors in list and merge into table
result_list <- map(1:7,~ myPagesource %>% html_nodes(str_c(".c",.x)) %>% html_text())
result_list2 <- map(c(5,6),~myPagesource %>% html_nodes(glue::glue("tr>td:nth-child({i})",i=.x)) %>% html_text())
result_list[[5]] <- c(result_list[[5]],result_list2[[1]])
result_list[[6]] <- c(result_list[[6]],result_list2[[2]])
result_df <- do.call("cbind", result_list)
colnames(result_df) <- result_df[1,]
result_df <- as.tibble(result_df[-1,])
```

[image]

You can do some data cleaning afterward.